# Cannot find a plugin which is able to handle the document being passed

Tags: dolphin, zip

When I double click a zip file in Dolphin I get the error:

```
Could not open file:///tmp/test.zip
Cannot find a plugin which is able to handle the document being passed
```

Don't remember when this error began to popup. But I could open zip files before.
What must be updated or installed to fix this?

Comment: What do you get if you run from the command line `file /tmp/test.zip`

Comment: `/tmp/test.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract, compression method=deflate`